# Obtaining the word count from a post in Jekyll for Github Pages?

Tags: html, github, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

Here's the code snippet that I'm currently using to see if a blog post exceeds over 120 words. If true, truncate the content and add a "READ MORE" link at the bottom of the post.

```
<div class="blogs">
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    <article class="post">          
      <h3><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/{{ site.blogs }}{{ post.title }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>

      {% assign wordCount = {{ post.content | size }} %}
      {% if wordCount > 120 %}
        <div class="entry">
            {{ post.content | truncatewords:120}}
        </div>

        <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url}}" class="read-more">Read More</a>
      {% else %}
        {{ post.content }}
      {% endif %}
    </article>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

When I commit this, I received an email from GitHub saying that there's a page error upon building, and nothing else was printed out.

I'm guessing it has to do with `{{ post.content }}` not being able to filter out the size, so I'm stuck.

How would I obtain the word count of individual blog posts, so that I'm able to truncate some of the posts with over 120 words in them? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`{{ post.content | size }}` gives you the number of characters in post.content string.

If you want to count word in a string, use `number_of_words` liquid filter.

```
{% assign wordCount = post.content | number_of_words %}
```

Note : you have a strange link in the post title `{{ site.baseurl }}/{{ site.blogs }}{{ post.title }}` I think it's `{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url}}` like in the read more link.

Comment: I added `site.blogs: blogs/` with the slash at the end in the `_config.yml`, so that's why I was doing it in a strange way. The `post.url` gives me a headache since it adds an extra slash at the front, which Jekyll removes the double-slashes when it is concatenated, which breaks the URL link. I don't know why at the moment, but I'm still learning as I go. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: `{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url}}` is the way to go here. For custom url for posts, see http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/

Answer (score 0):

While testing this locally, I have found out that `{{ post.content | size }}` does indeed give you the word count, since the `{{ post.content }}` is a string, albeit a long one.

Seeing how GitHub Pages didn't go with the `{% if ... %}` logic, I'm guessing there's something that's not executing correctly. Without much info, I am stuck.

So, yes, `{{ post.content | size }}` does give you the word count. The conditional flow of it, however, needs some more testing, as it just wouldn't execute correctly.

If anyone have more info, please let me know. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% if post.content | number_of_words > 120 %}
    {{ post.content | truncatewords:120 }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```